# Which Parquet file databricks will refer for schema while creating a table

Tags: azure, databricks, parquet, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm creating a external table in azure databricks on top of the ADLS parquet files using the syntax below.

create table if not exists <table_name>  using parquet location 'abfss://@'

This syntax will automatically infer the schema of the parquet file and create external table, now my question is when there is multiple files available(specially when files are different in structure) in the specified location, which file databricks will refer?

Most recent one or oldest one or random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and got below results.

These are my two parquet files with different schema as one will have less column than another.

[image]

when I created the table from the folder it took the only first file which means as in **alphabetical order**.

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE if not exists student1 USING parquet OPTIONS (path 'dbfs:/mnt/data/delta/');
select * from student1;
```

[image]

And its the same with pyspark dataframe also.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for your answer. Can you please let me know how this behaves when there are folders within the given location?
Is it taking the alphabetic first file within the first folder or in different manner?

Comment: Usually parquets files will have same schema for all files. when I tested the above with one file in `one` folder and another in `two` folder which two are in same `delta` folder like this https://i.imgur.com/Z72Zv1J.png, it gave me like this https://i.imgur.com/beTbjuZ.png. So it wants us specify the total path till last folder, if in that folder if there are different schema, then it took the first file in alphabetical order for me. Also, in the above repro if the file with more columns is first, then in the table it gave me null values for the extra column https://i.imgur.com/buct9i9.png